# Appium 2.0 w3c touchaction not able to use xy only in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, appium

I was given some code as an example to the new W3C standards with Appium 2.0 and dot net 5 and I tried it however it needs an element to touch and I am using this tap when I do not have any element.I bolded the part I cant seem to figure out what to use as again I have no element.

```
        var touch = new PointerInputDevice(PointerKind.Touch, "finger");

        // Create a sequence for tap
        var sequence = new ActionSequence(touch);

        PointerEventProperties pointerEventProperties = new PointerEventProperties();
        pointerEventProperties.Pressure = 1;

        **var move = touch.CreatePointerMove(,263, 495, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));**
        //var move = touch.CreatePointerMove(elementToTouch, elementToTouch.Location.X, elementToTouch.Location.Y, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        var action = touch.CreatePointerDown(MouseButton.Touch, pointerEventProperties);
        var pouse = touch.CreatePause(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        var action2 = touch.CreatePointerUp(MouseButton.Touch);

        sequence.AddAction(move);
        sequence.AddAction(action);
       sequence.AddAction(pouse);
        sequence.AddAction(action2);

        var actions_seq = new List<ActionSequence>
```

{
sequence
};

```
          _IOSdriver.PerformActions(actions_seq);
```